# Setting a shortcut's cwd

Tags: linux-mint, symlink, desktop-shortcuts, cwd, caja

I have a program that works correctly if:

1. I run it from the command line in its own directory.
2. I run it from the command line from wherever, using `cd /path/to/prog && ./prog`.
3. I double-click it in Caja.
4. I right-click it in Caja, pick Make Link, and double-click the link.

It doesn't work if:

1. I run it from the command line from a different directory with the correct relative path.  (Many program-specific errors are given about how it can't find files that are in its own subdirectories.)
2. I move the link mentioned above to the desktop, and double-click it there.  (A window *frame* pops up and immediately disappears, without even being filled in.)
3. I make a Launcher on the desktop and point it to the program.  (Ibid.)
4. I make a Launcher on the desktop and point it to `cd /path/to/prog && ./prog`.  (Ibid.)

AFAICT all the non-working methods are due to the `cwd` being incorrect.

So, **how do I simply make a working shortcut to this program on the desktop?**

Or, how can I set a shortcut's `cwd` properly, without additional workarounds like making a one-liner bash launcher script and making a shortcut to that?

Linux Mint 18.1 MATE 64-bit.

Update:  The launcher interface doesn't seem to have a Path option:

[image]

Comment: OK.  btw `journalctl -b` only confirmed what I'd figured out (that it was in the wrong `cmd`) already--it was full of identical segfaults from the program in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it with the launcher UI shown, and then edit the resulting `~/Desktop/*.desktop` file yourself to add a `Path=...` line.  What doesn't work is if you put `Exec=prog_name` rather than duplicating the whole path.  So it has to look like:

```
...
Exec=/path/to/prog
Path=/path/to/
...
```

Comment: `Exec=prog_name` works too as long as `prog_name` is in your `PATH`

Comment: I think if it were in my `PATH` then the whole program would work in the first place...anyway, duly noted.